# Cant render API data, .map error using Google Books API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

Pretty new to React, still learning. I was trying to make this Book Finder app using Google Books API, and then when I wanted to map the data, first time everything worked perfectly, but after that one time I started getting this error:

[image: Error]

Keep in mind that the first time I ran the code everything worked, I was even fixing some CSS properties and it re-rendered fine.
I tried a lot of things, I do know that you can't use .map on objects, and I checked, the API data was and object.

Result of typeof() for the given API data
[image: Result of typeof() for the given API data]

Heres the code:

MainContainer.tsx

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import List from "./List";
import Search from "./Search";
import request from "superagent";

export default function MainContainer() {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

    function handleChange(e: any) {
        setBooks(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleSearch(e: any) {
        e.preventDefault();
        request
            .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
            .query({ q: setBooks })
            .then((data) => {
                setBooks([...books])
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <Search
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handleSearch={handleSearch}
            />
            <List books={books}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

List.tsx

```js
import Card from "./Card"

export default function List(props: any) {

    return (
        <div className="list-container">

            {

                props.books && props.books.length > 0 ?
                    props.books.map(function (book: any) {
                        return (
                            <Card
                                key={book.id}
                                image={book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}
                                title={book.volumeInfo.title}
                                author={book.volumeInfo.authors}
                                published={book.volumeInfo.publishedDate}
                            />
                        )
                    }) : <p className="np-data">No books yet...</p>
            }

        </div>
    )
}
```

Card.tsx

```js
export default function Card(props: any) {
    return (
        <div className="card">

            <img src={props.image} alt="" />
            <div className="card-desc">

                <h3 className="title">{props.title}</h3>
                <h4 className="author">{props.author}</h4>
                <p className="published">{props.published}</p>

            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Again, I'm still learning React, this might be some dumb-typo-begginer error so yeah. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your `handleChange` your are using `setBooks(e.target.value);` which is a string. Make sure you are always passing an array in `setBooks` hook. Also check in your function `handleSearch` what are you passing in `setBooks`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two pieces of state here (the search query and the list of books), but you are using a single variable (`books`) to keep track of both.

In the `MainContainer` component, add this to create another state variable.

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
```

Update `handleChange` to this to update the search query variable.

```
function handleChange(e: any) {
  setQuery(e.target.value);
}
```

Update `handleSearch` to this to make a request with the last entered query and correctly set the `books` state variable.

```
function handleSearch(e: any) {
  e.preventDefault();
  request
    .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
    .query({ q: query})
    .then((data) => {
      setBooks(data.items)
    })
 }
```

It should work as expected now.

Comment: Yep that's it! I just edited the `setBooks(data.items)` to `setBooks(data.body.items)` and it all worked! Thanks man!